# Why doesn't this javascript code work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

Can someone check why my javascript code isn't working in Internet Explorer 9, but works normally in Firefox ??? Also code doesn't work in Google Chrome.

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>test</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function showF4(){
      document.getElementById('showF4').style.display = "block";
   }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <p><select class="selField" id="list_sel" name="list_type" >
         <option id="F4DOL" onmouseover="showForm7()" onmouseout="hideForm7()"            onclick="showF4()"  value="F4 Document List"> F4 Document List </option>

      </select></p>
   </form>

   <div id="showF4" style="display: none">
      <p><font color="red">*</font>Feature:
      <input   id="f4_input"  name="f4_input" type="text" value="" /> </p>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the js functions showForm7() & hideForm7() ?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-70901257 - These events aren't defined for `<option />` elements

Comment: forget showForm7() & hideForm7()  , there aren't important , just look showF4() , I want to display block show f4 , when I click dropdown menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<option id="F4DOL" onmouseover="showForm7()" onmouseout="hideForm7()" onclick="showF4()"  value="F4 Document List"> F4 Document List </option>
```

`option`s don't have those events like `onClick`, its the select box that does. Move those out of `option` to `select` and change to appropriate methods like `onChange` etc.

Comment: I tried with <select class="selField" id="list_sel" name="list_type" onchange="showF4()" >
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option id="F4DOL"   value="F4 Document List"> F4 Document List </option>

</select>

Comment: and what's the result

Comment: and it works in IE , but this will make me trouble, because , I will need to change completly javascript code, i s tehere any other solution, to call every time different javascript function , when I click on <option tag>

Comment: You have to do what you have to do. You can surely find some hacks around the web but option tag by default does not have those events.

Comment: Besides, you have many ways of simplifying it using the `select` element. There are more events you can use, like onMouseOver, onChange, onClick etc

Answer (score 0):

So I found the following:

http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/4959.htm

And one of the guys gave this as the answer

```
hi, 
your method of setting the style of elements: 

element.style.property="something";

will not work in ie. How to set styles with javascript depends not only on the browser, but in some cases also on other conditions, as if the style is inline or comes from css and on other things (for this see eg. quirksmode.org).
Therefore you might prefer to add styles for a specific class in your stylesheet, let's say 

.noshow {visibility: hidden;}

and then use js to switch between visible and not by saying 

element.className="noshow";

and 

element.className="";

Hope this helps.
```

Have a look, it might solve your problem